# Error Argument 3 passed to HookCore::callHookOn() must be of the type array, null given

Tags: prestashop, hook, prestashop-1.7

On Prestashop Store after update to 1.7.8.8 I have problems with blank pages on produt pages. It does not happen all the time, the same page after few refreshes loads properly. And then after few more it displays blank page again. Debug info:

```
 (1/1) FatalThrowableError

Type error: Argument 3 passed to HookCore::callHookOn() must be of the type array, null given, called in /home/ampero/nowa.ampero.pl/classes/Hook.php on line 944
in Hook.php line 422
at HookCore::callHookOn(object(APPageBuilder), 'filterProductContent', null)in Hook.php line 944
at HookCore::exec('filterProductContent', null, null, false, true, false, null, true)in ProductController.php line 384
at ProductControllerCore->initContent()in Controller.php line 306
at ControllerCore->run()in Dispatcher.php line 525
at DispatcherCore->dispatch()in index.php line 28
```

[image]

example url: https://ampero.pl/seria-slim/1018-mod-eth-modu%C5%82-ethernetowy-.html (error des not apear all the time)

1. I tried to unhook all unnecessary modules from displayRightColumnProduct, displayRightColumn and displayLeoProductTabContent.
2. I tried to enable, disable, clear cache

Comment: II walked around the problem but did not solve it. I overwrote the hook.php file to check if this parameter is null and block execution. The error does not show but still occurs. If anyone has an idea I would ask you to suggest it

Answer (score 0):

You have some module that is hooked into `filterProductContent`, and this module doesn't return an array in this hook.

One such module for a long time was `productcomments` module, one of the native modules. I suggest you check all the modules in the Design -> Positions -> `filterProductContent` hook. See if they are returning an array in their hook implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting a similar error on PrestaShop v1.7.7.5 since we updated the module `Faceted Search` to v3.11.0

```
TypeError Argument 3 passed to HookCore::callHookOn() must be of the type array, null given, called in /var/www/site/classes/Hook.php on line 927 
/var/www/site/classes/Hook.php:405 HookCore::callHookOn
/var/www/site/classes/Hook.php:927 HookCore::exec
/var/www/site/controllers/front/listing/CategoryController.php:113 CategoryControllerCore::init
/var/www/site/classes/controller/Controller.php:287 ControllerCore::run
/var/www/site/classes/Dispatcher.php:518 DispatcherCore::dispatch
/var/www/site/index.php:28 [main]
```

UPDATE:
Turns out it was the Advanced SEO module causing issues.

```
HookCore::callHookOn(object(AdvanceSeo), 'filterCategoryContent', null)
```

in Hook.php line 927